# I have a need to see all session scope for all logged in users in ColdFusion2018

Tags: ajax, session, struct, coldfusion, cfml

I start with this find;

```
<cfscript>
    app = application.getApplicationSettings().name;
    sessionCollection = application.sessionTracker.getSessionCollection(app);
</cfscript>
```

and then attempt to loop thru the collection;

```
<cfloop collection="#sessionCollection#" item="i">
    #StructFind(i, 'CurrentAction')#
</cfloop>
```

which fails with;
You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.

I have tried

```
#CurrentAction[i]#
```

which fails with;
Variable CURRENTACTION is undefined.

when I know for a fact it exists
(https://ibb.co/ZJwsKFS)

Ive tried dot notation as well.

The purpose is to identify an ajax listener activity for one user, and affect an action on another specific user as a response. I am under the impression I can send an action by sessionID end user. Please feel free to let me know if this is NOT possible.

Answer (score 5):

So this code:

```
<cfset x = {
    a = 1
    , b = 2
    , c = 3
}>

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop collection="#x#" item="i">
        <li>#i#</li>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Outputs the following:

- A
- B
- C

Which means that `i` is the key of the struct defined in the `collection` attribute. Your code is trying to find a key in the collection (struct), but you're referencing the wrong variable.

To find the value of `B`, you would do `StructFind(x, "b")`. You don't need the `cfloop` either, you just need to check if the key exists, then get the value.

```
<cfset someVariable = "">
<cfif structKeyExists(x, "b")>
    <cfset someVariable = structFind(x, "b")>
</cfif>
```